# Meteor Merge two cursors data of same collection

Tags: meteor

I have a strange problem here.

I want to merger two cursors data into single cursor of same collection.

Here is my code

```
{{#each friendsPolls.data}}
    {{#if username}}
        {{#each questions}}
            {{question}}
        {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

**app.js**

```
 Questions:function(){
    Meteor.call('isFbExists', this.username, function (error, result) {
        if(result) {
            var ee=Ques_Coll.find({owner:result._id});
        }
    })
}
```

How can I return the cursor to my template, where it substitutes the `{{question}}` value.

This function is called many times(length fb friends). Each time when this calls server method it checks whether the user exists in my database or not.

If he already exists then I search for his documents and want to display them
However, if I do like above the data is override and it returns the last user results only.

So,each time it search in collection I want to append that cursor to existing one

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, but I think you don't actually want to merge anything, you just need to get a simple find, if I understood correctly, just can do this: collect all ids of the friends and then do ´Ques_Coll.find({owner: {$in: arrayOfFriendIds}})´ (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/selectors)

Comment: also you probably don't need Meteor.call you can use a regular subscription.